# Building array of data in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I have the results of a search in an instance var called `@results`. Each item is an album. I have looped over the result set and added all the album parent collection id's to a var called `@collections`. This is done as below:

```
 @results.each do |album|
  @collections << album.collection_id
end

@collections = @collections.uniq
```

I now need to re iterate over the @results and create a child array of each album id that belongs in each collection.

I will then be able to use this to build nice output in my view.

I am rather confused as to how to build that child array of album id's per collection id.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I now need to re iterate over the @results and create a child array of each album id that belongs in each collection.

You need to use [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method :

```
child_array_by_id = @results.group_by { |album| album.collection_id }
@collections = child_array_by_id.keys
# now iterate
child_array_by_id.each do |id_key, val|
   # your code
end
```

Now you don't need the below to get the `@collection` array also. Because `child_array_by_id.keys` is giving you the same.

```
@results.each do |album|
  @collections << album.collection_id
end

@collections = @collections.uniq
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Still trying to wrap my head around how it works but thanks!